# How to keep old data in REACT component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Well, I think it might be a silly question to ask but trust me I am stuck and want to solve my problem. Actually, I used the `react-waypoint` infinite scroller in my application and it working fine. I fetched data from a server through API and I passed data through props into another component. It showing correctly for the first initial data but when I scroll down and in this case I hit an API and it fetches new data so here I am updating it state, my old data got lost and new data replaced but here I want to keep old data as well, when I scroll down then I want to update the state and want to pass down through props `but I did not want to lose my old data I want old and new data in one list` . could someone please help me how to solve my problem. I will share my code.

**Code ( Index.JS )**

```
               <div className="row">
                {properties &&
                  properties.items.map((item, index) => (
                    <PropertyDetail
                      image={item.inventoryImages[0].secureUrl}
                      key={index}
                    />
                  ))}
              </div>

              <Waypoint onEnter={onEnterAddPropModalWaypoint} />
```

**PropertyDetail.js**

```
import React from "react";

const PropertyDetail = ({ image }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-md-4 mb-4">
        <img
          src={image}
          alt="newImage"
          style={{ height: "150px", width: "100%" }}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PropertyDetail;
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't comprehend well but if you're trying to persist an old array data you can use

```
const [properties, setProperties] = useState([]) // don't forget the initial []

// somewhere where you do your api call
setData([...properties, ...response.properties]);
```

Comment: @crmacase . I am calling this function to update data 

  `async function onEnterAddPropModalWaypoint() {
    setOffset(offset + 3);
    const result = await axios.get(
      `${config.apiPath}/api/inventory/find?limit=3&offset=${offset}&userId=240&isActive=1&web=true`
    );

    setProperties([...properties, ...result.data]);
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Need to see more of your code; specifically where are you setting the state?  But basically you would call setState, or use a hook to update the state, and keep the previous state.

```js
this.setState({
  properties: [...this.properties, ...newData]
})
```

or, if you are using hooks, something like:

```js
const [properties, setProperties] = useState([]);

this.getMoreData().then(results => {
  this.setProperties([...properties, ...results]);
})
```

Comment: I am getting this error : `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance`